# Parsing Facebook JSON Array

Tags: java, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am really stuck. I am trying to query nearby places from facebook and I actually get the results in a json format. This is the code I use.

```
@Override

public void getNearbyPlaces(final Session session){
        Request request = Request.newPlacesSearchRequest(session, _gpsTracker.getLocation(), 8000, 1, "restaurant", new Request.GraphPlaceListCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphPlace> places, Response response) {
            ListIterator<GraphPlace> _allplaces =    places.listIterator();
             while(_allplaces.hasNext()){ 
                 String singlePlace = _allplaces.next().toString();         
             }

            if(response.getError() != null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

and this is the result I get

```
GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphPlace, state={"id":"196223377081320","category":"Local business","location":{"state":"","zip":"","longitude":32.6246565296,"latitude":0.23724219554666,"country":"Uganda","city":"Kampala","street":""},"category_list":[{"id":"273819889375819","name":"Restaurant"},{"id":"164243073639257","name":"Hotel"}],"name":"Munyonyo Speke Resort"}}
```

However, I have failed to extract the name, id and the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
@Override

public void getNearbyPlaces(final Session session){

    Request request = Request.newPlacesSearchRequest(session, _gpsTracker.getLocation(), 8000, 1, "restaurant", new Request.GraphPlaceListCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphPlace> places, Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (GraphPlace graphPlace : places) {
                graphPlace.getId();
                graphPlace.getName();
                graphPlace.getLocation().getLatitude();
                graphPlace.getLocation().getLongitude();
            }
            if(response.getError() != null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();
}
```